# How to use graphql-type-json with NestJS

Tags: graphql, nestjs

i Have following response that needs to go under GraphQL Query:

```
{
  '0xF7446f0...9a496aE94Cf9d42': { balances: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  '0xc01679F6496...95c86f9DEc63a': { balances: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
}
```

Using nestjs together with `graphql-type-json` and my code looks like this

```
@ObjectType()
export class BalancesResponse {
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  error?: string;

  @Field((type) => JSON)
  balances: any;
}
```

but when i try to execute the requests i got this error:

`"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field BalancesResponse.balances."`

Any idea how to return it, i want to return all of the key-value pairs in the object and my key to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL [does not support](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/101) dictionary types. You can only query defined (i.e. known in advance) fields.

You could, however, refactor the response object to be an array:

```json
[
  { key: '0xF7446f0...9a496aE94Cf9d42', balances: [ ... ] },
  { key: '0xc01679F6496...95c86f9DEc63a', balances: [ ... ] }
]
```

The corresponding type definition would be:

```js
@ObjectType()
export class BalanceResponse {
  @Field()
  key: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  error?: string;

  @Field((type) => JSON)
  balances: any;
}

...
@Query(() => [BalanceResponse])
async getBalance(): Promise<BalanceResponse[]>
```

Alternatively, you are free to lose the typing by declaring the whole response object as a GraphQL JSON. Then you can return your original response from the endpoint:

```js
// not a GraphQL class anymore
export class BalancesResponse {
  error?: string;
  balances: Balance;
}

...
@Query(() => JSON)
async getBalance(): Promise<Record<string, BalancesResponse>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `GraphQLJSONObject` de `graphql-type-json`

```
import { GraphQLJSONObject } from 'graphql-type-json';

@ObjectType()
export class BalancesResponse {
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  error?: string;

  @Field(() => [GraphQLJSONObject], {
    nullable: true,
    description: 'Balance details',
  })
  balances: Record<string, any>[];
}
```

But I would only use it in extreme cases, such as in the development stage when the response typing is not yet defined.

Because although you will get the information, it gets complicated when you want to make a mutation. In addition to the fact that the client of your graph is going to have to retrieve a lot of information that it may not need.